# De duplication in AlertManager for dynamic label values

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a prometheus rule to get alerts when messages in rabbitmq have crossed the threshold. I have exposed metrics for RabbitMQ /metrics/per-object to get the queue name as well. When the alert gets fired, it keeps on firing for different value of messages_num e.g it gets fired at 89 then it gets fired at 90 creating many alert notifications.

```
name: Prometheus_rabbitmq_messages_piled_up_Alert
expr: rabbitmq_queue_messages_ready > 50
labels:
   group: RabbitMQ
   messages_num: {{ $value }}
   priority: LOW
annotations:
   summary: Prometheus Alert for Messages have piled up in RabbitMQ Cluster.
```

I tried to use inhibit rules, but I am not understanding how to use it in my situation. From the examples it says something like if severity is critical it will inhibit severity warning. In my case I cannot define the number of messages, I just want one alert if it reaches the threshold. I understand that prometheus will always fire if condition is true so the set of settings must be in alertmanager. My Alertmanager settings are

```
config:
  global: 
    resolve_timeout: 5m
  route:
    group_by: ['alertname']
    group_wait: 30s
    repeat_interval: 1h
    receiver: 'null'
    routes:
    - receiver: 'prometheus-msteams'
      matchers:
        - group =~ "RabbitMQ"
```

and my Receiver settings are

```
 receivers:
    - name: 'null'
    - name: 'prometheus-msteams'
      webhook_configs:
      - send_resolved: false
        url: [URL]
```

Comment: Why do you need value as a label of alert in the first place? It is recommended not to put dynamic content into labels. Wouldn't adding value to `summary` or `description` of your alert be sufficient?

Comment: let me remove dynamic labels and test it. Will get back with the update

Comment: @markalex Removing dynamic labels didnt help. Still getting duplicates for same alert.

Comment: @MahnoorFatima was you able to find the root reason to this problem?

Comment: @DeamonMV No, not really. I removed all dynamic labels. I tried adding group wait and whatever documentation suggested, didnt work as expected.

Comment: @markalex I can assume that you have HA alertmanager, so alertmanager have flag --cluster.peer-timeout. Try to set --cluster.peer-timeout=1m and then for yours all routes set group_wait: 90s -- maybe this will help

Comment: @DeamonMV, it seems you've failed to address correct user: I'm not the OP. But I hope your advice might help actual OP too.

Comment: @DeamonMV Thank you. I will give it a shot. Will get back to you.